# Amazon Build fails with The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, build, aws-codepipeline

I'm new on the whole aws stuff and stuck with the deployment.
I've the typical angular basic example app which I'd like to be build and deployed to elasticbeanstalk automatically as soon as master is changed.

I've setup a codepipeline. Code is checked out automatically from Bitbucket.
But when it's build, I've got this error always:

> The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
> project definition could not be found.

The local build does work, only on AWS it's not working

This is my buildspec:

```
  version: 0.2
  phases:
    install:
      runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 10
      commands:
      - npm install -y npm@latest
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - rm package-lock.json
  
     pre_build:
       commands:
       - npm install

     build:
       commands:
       - echo build started on `date`
       - ng build
       - ls -l -F

artifacts:
  files:
    - '/'
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: 'dist*'
paths:
- node_modules/
```

I also got this error message, don't know if it has something to do with it:

> [Container] 2021/04/03 22:32:00 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
> [Container] 2021/04/03 22:32:00 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for dist*

Comment: What is your code pipeline setup?

Comment: What do You mean by that?

Comment: I have 3 steps. Code commitnfrom bitbucket. This is green. Build on aws, this fails and deploy also on aws to beanstalk. Is failing because build does not work